# Javascript: Round up and down to the nearest 5, then find a common denominator

Tags: javascript, jquery, rounding

iam looking for a way to Round up AND down to the nearerst 5 and then find a great common denominator of the two numbers.
I need it for the  caption of a y-skale on a chart.

This is my code so far:

```
function toN5( x ) {
    var i = 1;
    while( x >= 100 ) {
        x/=10; 
        i*=10;
    }
    var remainder = x % 5;
    var distance_to_5 = (5 - remainder) % 5;
    return (x + distance_to_5) * i;
}
```

The target is something like this:
The maximal value (round up to the nearest 5)

```
1379.8 -> 1500
```

And the other way round - minimal value (round down to the nearest 5)

```
41.8 -> 0
```

Then i want to find a  common denominator like 250 or 500

> 0 -> 250 -> 500 -> 750 -> 1000 -> 1250 -> 1500

or:

```
0 -> 500 -> 1000 -> 1500
```

Is ther a way to do something like that? Thanks a lot

Comment: 1379.8 rounded up to the nearest 5 would be 1380. Do you mean "to the nearest 500"?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by round to the nearest 5? In your first and second examples, you're actually rounding to the nearest 500. Or to the nearest 250, depending on how you look at it.

Answer (score 52):

If you wanted to round *x* to the nearest 500, you could divide it by 500, round it to the nearest integer, then multiply it by 500 again:

```
x_rounded = 500 * Math.round(x/500);
```

To round it to the nearest *y*, replace 500 with *y*:

```
x_rounded = 250 * Math.round(x/250);
```

Comment: Sounds great, but the problem ist, that the values could be huge und very tiny. For Example 1500 and 0.23.

Comment: Then you need to be more specific for us about how you want to round the number. Currently, your question doesn't actually say what you apparently mean.

Comment: Very nice answer. If I wanted to around to nearest 0.05 or 0.1, I just need to do 0.05* Math.round(x/0.05)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's too bad questions like this get closed. It's obviously helping people.

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully my maths is correct but here are various ways of "rounding"

```
function sigfig(n, sf) {
    sf = sf - Math.floor(Math.log(n) / Math.LN10) - 1;
    sf = Math.pow(10, sf);
    n = Math.round(n * sf);
    n = n / sf;
    return n;
}

function precision(n, dp) {
    dp = Math.pow(10, dp);
    n = n * dp;
    n = Math.round(n);
    n = n / dp;
    return n;
}

function nearest(n, v) {
    n = n / v;
    n = Math.round(n) * v;
    return n;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2wUX6/)

Answer (score 1):

Using [this api](https://smittycraft.github.io/apis/math.js), you can round any number to the nearest multiple of any number, up or down, with this command:

`$scm.round(number to be rounded).toNearest(multiple to which you want to round);`

For example, if you wanted to round 536 to the nearest 500, you would use:

`$scm.round(536).toNearest(500);`

Comment: Oops, I just realized the question was asked 5 years ago. Can an admin close it? It seems like there isn't any activity...