# What is the most compact, elegant and efficient way of rounding to the nearest 5 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

I want a function that does

```
NearestFive(3) --> 5
NearestFive(5) --> 0
NearestFive(6) --> 5
```

if that makes sense. Best I can come up with is

```
function NearestFive ( x )
{
   var r = x % 5; 
   if ( r == 0 ) return x; 
   else if ( r > 2 ) return x + 5 - r;
   else return x - r;
}
```

but I'm wondering if it's possible to consolidate those steps or introduce bitshift operations to add efficiency?

For example, running two comparisons

1. `r == 0`
2. `r > 2`

may not be necessary since `r > 2` implies `r == 0`.

Comment: Did you search at all, there seems to be [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953384/javascript-round-up-to-the-next-multiple-of-5) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535817/javascript-round-up-and-down-to-the-nearest-5-then-find-a-common-denominator) and several others that show different ways of doing this, surely some of them must be efficient enough ?

Comment: For integers only as shown in your example code?

Comment: `return ((x+2) / 5) * 5;`

Comment: Is the second example a mistake? `5 -> 0` or `5 -> 5`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trivial way to "round to the nearest X" is to divide by X, round to the nearest integer, then multiply by X again.

```
function NearestX(num, factor) {
    return Math.round(num/factor)*factor;
}
```

This even works for rounding to the nearest fractional part (eg. nearest 0.1)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your browser this could run fast:

```
function NearestFive5 ( x )
{
   return (((x+2)/5)>>0) * 5;
}
```

In my browser performance is equal with `Math.round(x/5)*5`, but both are notably faster than the version you posted in the question.